# Diferença de retornar um new ResponseEntity e um ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(alunoService.addAluno(aluno));
```

---

```
Aluno novoAluno = alunoService.addAluno(aluno);
return new ResponseEntity<>(novoAluno, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Testei das duas formas aqui no meu projeto e as duas funcionaram normalmente, mas eu queria saber qual prática é melhor, ou isso é questão de preferência?

Só quero saber a diferença das duas formas mesmo, na minha visão, quando faço da segunda maneira o código fica mais legível.

Answer (score 9):

Quando vc cria uma instância de `ResponseEntity` manualmente vc não pode mais
alterá-la.

Digamos que vc queira adicionar cabeçalhos, vc não conseguiria fazendo como
abaixo, pois `getHeaders()` retorna uma versão de `HttpHeaders` que não suporta
operações que o modifiquem (veja
[readOnlyHttpHeaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#readOnlyHttpHeaders(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders))).

```java
var response = new ResponseEntity<>(new Aluno(), HttpStatus.CREATED);

response.getHeaders().setLastModified(Instant.now()); // Lança UnsupportedOperationException

return response;
```

O método `status()` é um dos métodos que retornam um builder de `ResponseEntity`
que pode ser personalizado de acordo com as suas necessidades.

```java
return ResponseEntity
  .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .lastModified(Instant.now())
  .header("Custom-Header", "VALOR")
  .body(new Aluno());
```

Você pode ter o mesmo resultado do código acima assim:

```java
var headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setLastModified(Instant.now());
headers.set("Custom-Header", "VALOR");

return new ResponseEntity<>(new Aluno(), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Então, no seu caso, usar um ou outro não faz diferença (embora eu prefira a sua
primeira versão).

Contudo, quando vc precisa personalizar sua `ResponseEntity`, veja como usar o
builder deixa seu código mais conciso e, na minha opinião, melhor para ler.